# mobile menu scrolling works on desktop not mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I've created a mobile menu for my website, the problem is the menu items are quite long. The scrolling works on desktop browsers (when testing in mobile size), yet on my iphone, it doesn't work (untested on android).

http://182.160.156.158/~semphnorg (specifically the 'resources' menu item to see how it's working / not working)

The CSS for the menu is:

```
.m-mobile-menu *{position:relative}
.m-mobile-menu{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:auto;overflow-y:scroll;opacity:0;visibility:hidden;transition:all 0.5s;-ms-transform:translateY(25px);-o-transform:translateY(25px);-webkit-transform:translateY(25px);transform:translateY(25px);overflow-x:hidden;z-index:-1}
.m-mobile-menu ul{padding-top:55px;z-index:99;margin:0}
.m-mobile-menu ul li.a-menu-close{position:absolute;top:0;right:0;z-index:1;background:#004067}
.m-mobile-menu ul li.a-menu-close > a{float:left;display:block;width:calc(100% - 85px);border:0;background:transparent}
.m-mobile-menu ul li.a-menu-close > a > span{font-size:160%;margin-right:15px}
.m-mobile-menu ul li.a-menu-close > a:last-child{float:right;background:#009bff;display:table;width:auto}
.m-mobile-menu ul li.a-menu-close > a:last-child > span{margin-right:0}
.m-mobile-menu li{border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,80,117,.3);background:#fff;width:100%;margin:0;list-style:none}
.m-mobile-menu li > a,.m-mobile-menu li > span{color:#009bff}
.m-mobile-menu li:hover{background:#009bff}
.m-mobile-menu li:hover > a,.m-mobile-menu li:hover > span{color:#fff}
.m-mobile-menu li.deeper > a:after{content:"\f105";display:block;position:absolute;top:50%;right:15px;font-family:'FontAwesome';text-rendering:auto;color:#009bff;font-size:160%;margin-top:-15px;font-weight:400}
.m-mobile-menu li.deeper:hover > a:after{color:#fff}
.m-mobile-menu li > a{font-family:'open-sans',sans-serif;font-weight:700;font-size:120%;padding:24px 30px 18px;display:block;line-height:1;color:#009bff;text-decoration:none}
.m-mobile-menu li > a > i{display:none}
.m-mobile-menu .m-main-menu-child {position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; opacity: 0;-webkit-transform:translateX(100%);-o-transform:translateX(100%);-ms-transform: translateX(100%);transform:translateX(100%);z-index:0;visibility:hidden;display:none;transition-delay: 0.5s; }
.m-mobile-menu .m-main-menu-child.is-open {z-index:1;opacity:1;visibility:visible;display:block;transition-delay:0s}
.m-menu-open { position:fixed;top:0;overflow:hidden; z-index: -1}
.m-mobile-menu .mobile-menu{transition:all 0.5s}
.u-overlay{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;background:rgba(89,89,91,.50);opacity:0;visibility:hidden;transition:0.5s all}
.m-mobile-menu .a-link-262{display:none!important}
.m-menu-open .u-overlay{opacity:1;visibility:visible;z-index:2}
.m-menu-open .content{overflow:hidden;height:100vh}
.m-menu-open .m-mobile-menu{opacity:1;visibility:visible;z-index:5000;-ms-transform:translateY(0);-o-transform:translateY(0);-webkit-transform:translateY(0);transform:translateY(0)}
.u-overlay { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: rgba(89, 89, 91, .50); opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; transition: 0.5s all; }
.m-menu-open .u-overlay { opacity: 1; visibility: visible; z-index: 2; }
```

The javascript is:

```
$('.js-toggle-menu').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body').addClass('m-menu-open');
  });
  $('.js-close-menu').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body').removeClass('m-menu-open');
    $('.m-mobile-menu .mobile-menu').css({
      '-webkit-transform' : 'translateX( 0 )',
      '-moz-transform'    : 'translateX( 0 )',
      '-ms-transform'     : 'translateX( 0 )',
      '-o-transform'      : 'translateX( 0 )',
      'transform'         : 'translateX( 0 )'
    }).attr('transform', 0);
  });
  $('.js-mobile-menu .js-back-child-menu').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var transform = $('.m-mobile-menu .mobile-menu').attr('transform') - 100;
    $('.m-mobile-menu .mobile-menu').css({
      '-webkit-transform' : 'translateX( -' + transform + '% )',
      '-moz-transform'    : 'translateX( -' + transform + '% )',
      '-ms-transform'     : 'translateX( -' + transform + '% )',
      '-o-transform'      : 'translateX( -' + transform + '% )',
      'transform'         : 'translateX( -' + transform + '% )'
    }).attr('transform', transform);
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('is-open');       
  });
  $('.js-mobile-menu .js-open-child-menu').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var transform = $(this).parent().attr('transform');
    $(this).parent().find('.m-main-menu-child').first().addClass('is-open');
    $(".m-main-menu-child, .m-mobile-menu").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
    $('.m-mobile-menu .mobile-menu').css({
      '-webkit-transform' : 'translateX( -' + transform + '% )',
      '-moz-transform'    : 'translateX( -' + transform + '% )',
      '-ms-transform'     : 'translateX( -' + transform + '% )',
      '-o-transform'      : 'translateX( -' + transform + '% )',
      'transform'         : 'translateX( -' + transform + '% )'
    }).attr('transform', transform);        
  });
  $('.js-trigger-sub-menu').click(function(){
    $('.m-submenu').toggleClass('a-active');
  });
  $('.js-no-link').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Comment: add `height: 100%; overflow-y: auto;` to `.m-mobile-menu .m-main-menu-child.is-open`

Comment: Unfortunately that messes with the next level of the menu, because of the overflow, the last level of menu items aren't showing.